# Mac OS X Desktop runs slow when I open two windows in the same desktop but not when in separate "spaces"

Tags: mac, desktop

When I open two windows of any processor-heavy application like games on one desktop it lags and makes the computer run slow, but when I keep these windows in separate "spaces", they seem to work just fine. Does anyone know why this happens and how I can make it so it doesn't?

Comment: Does this lag lessen if you completely hide one window behind the other in the same Space? I think you potentially have 'GPU-lag', as it's trying to draw twice as much at one time. Having one on a separate Space means it's not having to be drawn at all.

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing. I checked the activity monitor and it turns out there are two separate renderers running at the same time making the CPU overload. Hiding one over the other doesn't seem to change anything. If that's the case, then the culprit is probably just my processor.

Comment: Maybe check inside the games themselves; see if you have options like 'hardware skinning', vertex buffers etc off, as this will throw a lot of the processing back onto the CPU instead of the GPU. Often, the first 'guess' an app makes as to what your graphics settings should be is based on internal optimisations invisible to the user. Sometimes turning graphics down will un-optimise some aspects, making it slower rather than faster. You'd need to talk to the individual game makers for more specifics.